# SSH 1.7.14 installation for Python on Windows (package directory ssh does not exist)

Tags: python, windows, ssh

I've downloaded SSH 1.7.14 from this link: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ssh/1.7.14

It is a .tar.gz file. I extracted the files out and tried to set up the module for my Python 2.7.

I typed in the command from a `cmd` window as follows:

```
python C:\Users\TestUser\Downloads\ssh-1.7.14\setup.py build
```

But I've got the error message below:

```
running build
running build_py
error: package directory 'ssh' does not exist
```

So I tried another command argument:

```
python C:\Users\TestUser\Downloads\ssh-1.7.14\setup.py install
```

However, I've got following error:

```
running install
running build
running build_py
error: package directory 'ssh' does not exist
```

So I am quite confused. How can I set up this module and run it correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As the author [states](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ssh/1.7.14), `ssh` is a fork of `paramiko` that has meanwhile been incorporated into `paramiko`, so you should try to install it instead, and update your scripts to reflect the change. Since you're on windows, you'll need to [install dependencies by hand](http://vijaymurthy.blogspot.pt/2011/03/installing-paramiko-for-windows.html) (notably, `pycrypto`)